# Android Toast doesnt show up

Tags: android, toast

I am trying to show toast on inserting content into the database. and then it finishes the activity.

1. Send Mail
2. Store Mail in Db
3. If Successfull show Toast for 10sec
4. finish(); Activity and return to the previous one.

code: http://pastebin.com/6aBjwCFh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `show()` your toast to display it:

```
Toast.makeText(ComposeActivity.this, "Mail Sent to " + tousername, 10).show();
```

Comment: That is a classic thing with Toast.Many people forget it :)